# JS non-enumerable function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to define a non-enumerable `toJSON` function on a prototype object without much luck. I'm hoping for something similar to ECMAScript 5 `toJSON`:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, { enumerable: false });
```

However this defines it as a property which cannot be accessed as a method.
[**EDIT**: Nick is wrong; it *can* be accessed as a method. His mistake was in code that is not shown in this question - see his comments on answers below, for details.]

I was hoping to be able to define the function in a non-enumerable fashion, as I was planning to define in the prototypes of all primitive types (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Array`, and `Object`), so that I can recursively apply the function through complex objects.

The end goal here is to be able JSONify a Backbone model/collection with nested collections recursively.

I guess in total I have two main questions:

1. Is it possible to define a non-enumerable function on a prototype? If so how?
2. Is there a better way to JSONify nested Backbone models?

Comment: A method by definition *is* a  property of an object. You're drawing a distinction that doesn't exist. If you want it to be non-enumerable, then obviously you're enumerating properties of an object.

Comment: Yes, however I would like it to be a non-enumerable property, in the same way that Object.defineProperty is non-enumerable. ie, is not iterated through when using `for (x in obj)`

Comment: Right. Again, a method is a property of an object that references a function. The code that you have is what you'd use to make the property non-enumerable.

Comment: To clarify @user2437417's point:  Nick's code *is correct* - so his question is a bit confused/confusing. When he says *"However this defines it as a property which cannot be accessed as a method."* - he is *wrong*; it **can** be accessed as a method. Reading his comment's on answers below, it turns out his *real problem* was that the way he accessed it was incorrect. If he had shown the line of code were he tried to use it - that didn't do what he wanted - this would have been immediately apparent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't get it, why can't you access it as a method?

```
var foo = {};

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () {console.log('foo.bar\'d!');}
});

foo.bar(); // foo.bar'd!
```

If you wanted it on the prototype, it's as easy as

```
Object.defineProperty(foo.prototype, /* etc */);
```

or even directly in [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
foo.prototype = Object.create(null, {
    'bar': {value: function () {/* ... */}}
});
```

However, unless you're creating instances of `foo`, it **won't** show up if you try to `foo.bar`, and only be visible as `foo.prototype.bar`.

If `foo` has it's own prototype (e.g. `foo = Object.create({})`), you can get it with  [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), add the property to that and then `foo.bar` would work even if it is not an instance.

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(foo); // get prototype
Object.defineProperty(proto, /* etc */);
```

You can see [visibility of enumerable vs non-enumerable properties **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#Detection_Table).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The problem was that I was using `get` instead of `value`, which I wasn't able to access as a function.

Comment: _get_ invokes the _function_ without passing any arguments, then pretends the property is equal to the `return` of the function, so you were doing `SJON()(args)` when you wanted to do `SJON(args)`

Comment: Okay. One last question if you don't mind; will this approach cause some of the same issues as extending the Object prototype with an enumerable function?

Comment: @NickMitchinson no, this will only add the property to the `foo` user object, he is not adding the property to foo.prototype ;)

Comment: Non-enumerable properties will show up as [described **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#Detection_Table). Also, editing.

Answer (score 2):

Paul S. is right about needing to set the property definition's `value` instead of a `get`, but I wanted to add that you don't need to pass `enumerable: false`, because false is the default for that option in `Object.defineProperty()` The answer can be simplified to:

```
var foo = {};    

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    value: function(){ console.log('calling bar!'); }
});

foo.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks, I only included it explicitly to make it clear in the question, but it's a good note that it isn't actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

Always you can avoid enumerable functions properties in object when you looping through it. And instead of define property in each object and set enumerable to false , you can create function which will call to any object with the property you want and put a condition to not take the property in the looping list. here is the example :

```
const obj = {
name: "myName",
title: "developer"
}


function prop() {
this.loop = function(i) {
    for (i in this) {
        if (typeof(this[i]) == "function") {
            continue;
        } else {
            console.log(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
prop.call(obj);
obj.loop(); 
output >>  myName, developer
```

Comment: Why/when would you use this technique, rather than marking your new function as non-enumerable?

Comment: For high performance, i will not go so deep but in v8 engine there algorithm says [ All then one ] this algorithm for global error object when you are writing Object.defineProperty(object, "property" => algorithm will work from this point and mini machine will start run to apply in recursion stack all objects and properties you have [All] then will take object and properties which defined [one] imagine if you have big objects you are killing your CPU literally , fn.call will work [!one then all] means if you didn't chose (this) then this will go for all (window object).